# "Trying to get property 'params' of non-object" for axios.delete. Backend: PHP front: React

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

*I'd like to add to this question. I believe my problem is in this statement:

```
$reservation->res_id = $data->res_id;
```

because I am getting a non-object error. Can anyone see how this should be written differently if I'm trying to get the object by res_id when clicked?

My backend runs well in Postman. I console.log that I am finding the correct id, the onClick is being recognized and results are showing. However, the item is not deleting.

I have tried different ways to write the axios.delete line including:

```
url/${id}--
url/${res_id: id}--
url/{id}
```

and the following. This last one seems to be recommended, but still is not working.

```js
reservationDelete(id: number) {
  console.log(id);
  axios.delete(`http://localhost/react-restaurant-booking-backend/delete.php/`, {
      params: {
        res_id: 'id'
      }
    })
    .then((res: any) => {
      console.log('Item clicked');
      console.log(res);

    })
}
```

````
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    var_dump($data);

    $reservation = new Reservations();

    $reservation->res_id = $data->params->res_id;

    $delete = $reservation->adminDeleteReservation($pdo);
    echo ($delete);

```Postman
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      [
        "params"
      ]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
        [
          "res_id"
        ]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
   }
````

Comment: Looks like a PHP message. Can you add the relevant PHP to your question?

Comment: Also, showing what your postman request looks like when it works would also be helpful.

Comment: is your php reading the params from the url or the body of the request ? (*also are you sure you need the trailing `/` in the url ?*)

Comment: added the php code, will add postman also

Comment: Okay, so afaik, `params` passes data through the URL, i.e. query string. You probably want to use `data`.

Comment: when I switch to data, I get a "failed to read delete.php" message

Comment: *I'd like to add to this question. I believe my problem is in this statement:
    $reservation->res_id = $data->res_id;
because I am getting a non-object error. Can anyone see how this should be written differently if I'm trying to get the object by res_id when clicked?